# display maps according to locations stored inside database per each record in gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-maps, gridview

I have one grid with list of details of users. I have address stored in database according to user. I have to display google map for each user in gridview.

I have tried code with javascript for google map in rowbound event of gridview dynamically by passing latitude & longitude(calculated from location of user), but it works for 1st row only (map has been displayed for 1st row only).

Can you suggest me any other solution?

Comment: show an useful part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code  seems show the map for a single user only, if you want show all the user you must pass all the user collection to the map and manage this collection adding eg a marker for every single user. Otherwise you must call the function once for a single user and show only this.

Comment: code inside rowdatabound event, so its loop for each user inside gridview, can you provide specific link?

Comment: A minor  ad `</script>` to `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">` if missing.  And controls the exact correspondence between `<div> id` of the map and the value that you use in `getElementById`

Comment: all values are getting in loop, just want to display map for each row

Comment: You want create the map for each row in a specified <div> for each User. where are the several div ?